# Download Views CSV automatically Daily

Tags: 7, views

I have a bunch of views/reports built for my client. The reviewers then click download csv for the excel file. They asked if the views could download themselves daily to a folder.

Is that possible? And could you share links or knowledge how to handle this. I have been trying to figure it out.

**Note**: Right now the user is downloading CSV's from Drupal 7, an install of Moodle 1.9 in a Drupal 6 Shell and Survey Monkey. After they download and combine using Excel, the user creates reports that way for the users we have come to our events. Being a Front-end developer, coding is not my strength.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to consider the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363) module (disclosure: I'm a co-maintainer of it) ... Here is a quote from that page:

> ... built of the idea of using SQL to get data out of a database and use XHTML and CSS to format it into web reports.
>
> It is designed to leverage existing knowledge of HTML, CSS, SQL and JavaScript to help you create rich interactive web reports.

Here is another quote from [Reasons for considering Forena](https://www.drupal.org/node/2358629), related to the "CSV" in the question here:

> Reports created by Forena (combined with SVGGraph and mPDF) can be saved (exported) as PDF documents with embedded graphs. Other supported formats for saving a report are **CSV**, XLS, DOC, HTML, etc.

My answer to "[How to retrieve data directly from a Drupal database](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/166)" contains like a 1 minute summary to explain the typical (about 3) steps for creating:

- a **connection** to an external database (typically by an admin).
- a custom **SQL query** (typically by an admin).
- a custom **report** (either by an admin, or by just any regular user who is either familiar with creating what is called 'FRX files', or otherwise using the WYSIWYG report editor).

These steps (without any PHP coding involved ...) are like the equivalent to writing the PHP coding as included in the question there.

For an **online demo** (prior to installing/testing Forena), refer to these links:

- [Reporting samples](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/samples), about data stored in some SQLite database, and including things like drill down reports, creating charts (using the [PHP SVG Graph library](http://www.goat1000.com/svggraph.php)), etc.
- [Forena Documentation](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help), which you also get in your own site after installing the module). It contains topics such as (incomplete list):

  - Module [installation and administration](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.setup), a kind of getting started guide.
  - [WYSIWYG Report Writing](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.reportingwysiwyg), using a report editor to facilitate the creation of reports.
  - [Site Building](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.sitebuilding), topics about integrations of Forena with other Drupal modules.
  - [Forena hooks](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.development), to use it in other (custom) modules.

Comment: Wow, Thank you for the answer. Right now the user is downloading csv's from Drupal 7, an install of Moodle 1.9 in a Drupal 6 Shell and Survey Monkey. After they download and combine using Excel, she creates reports that way for the users we have come to our events.
   
Being a Front-end developer, coding is not my strength. I will be spending some time today to read through this module.   If you have more to share based on that please share away! I still have a lot to learn. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules). It's just for Drupal 7, but it should allow you to integrate your view with rules.

[Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) might be another option, it can also work with rules, but might be have a bit of a learning curve to get it set up.